# Why does ElasticSearch return different aggregation results based on Term Order property?

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I have the following ElasticSearch Query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [],
            "must_not": [
                {
                    "range": {
                        "embedded_depth": { // <-- a property on the document stored in the index.
                            "gt": 0
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "duplicates": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "content_blake3", // <-- stores a hash value
                "min_doc_count": 2,
                "size": 1000,
                "order": {
                    "_count": "desc"
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "size": {
                    "sum": {
                        "field": "fs.size" // <-- stores file size value.
                    }
                },
                "duplicate_top_hits": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "_source": [
                            "content_blake3",
                            "file_name",
                            "fs.uri",
                            "fs.created",
                            "fs.modified",
                            "fs.size"
                        ],
                        "size": 1,
                        "sort": [
                            {
                                "fs.created": {
                                    "order": "asc"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "size": 0 // <-- return 0 hits, return aggregated results only.
}
```

The query is toggled on the Terms > Order property like so:

```
                "order": {
                    "_count": "desc"
                }
```

or

```
                "order": {
                    "size": "desc"
                }
```

I have also used the:

```
  "track_total_hits": true
```

To ensure I am working with the same volume of search results.

## What is happening ?

When the query is toggled as you see above, the `size` based `desc` sort returns a drastically smaller result set than the `_count` based `desc` sort. The two data sets returned by each respective query are radically different which is leading to a very confused UX.

Can anyone explain why?

Is this right way of doing this?

Is there another this query can be done?